# Use kernel.environnement in Symfony Expression Language

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I am using Symfony 4.4 and I want to grant access to some routes only in `dev` or `test` environments.

My route is defined (using Api Platform) in the entity by:

```
*          "postUserTest"={
*              "security" = "'%kernel.environment%' !== 'prod'",
*              "method"="POST",
```

I tried to dump directly the result of Expression Language:

```
// $env = prod
$env = $this->getParameter('kernel.environment');
// $result0 = '%kernel.environment%'
$result0 = $expressionLanguage->evaluate("'%kernel.environment%'");
// $result1 = false
$result1 = $expressionLanguage->evaluate("'%kernel.environment%' === 'prod'");
// $result2 = true
$result2 = $expressionLanguage->evaluate("'%kernel.environment%' !== 'prod'");
```

I understand `'%kernel.environment%'` is not parsed, but how can I use the environnement ? I do find any example in documentation, is it possible ?

I expect this result:

```
$result1 = $expressionLanguage->evaluate("'%kernel.environment%' === 'prod'");
```

to be true in prod environment, now it's false.

Answer (score 0):

There are simpler ways to do that.

For example,

- SF>5: you can add a `when@dev:` section in a routing YAML or `#[When(env: 'dev')]` / `@When(env: 'dev')` as annotation should work.
- SF 4: put a YAML routing file in a `routes/dev/` folder as described here: https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/quick_tour/the_architecture.html
- SF 3: put your route in `app/config/routing_dev.yml`

Comment: I am using Symfony 4.4, it's not available